# TinyMCE custom plugin, how to make a word automatically selected based on current cursor position?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

Making a custom plugin for TinyMCE, I wonder how to make a word automatically selected based on current cursor position, like in the the Wordpress "Add link" plugin.

I've searched the Wordpress TinyMCe Wplink code and TinyMCE Docs but I've got no reference....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like below

```
if (editor.selection.isCollapsed()) {
    var selRng = editor.selection.getRng();
    selRng.expand("word"); //expands the DOM range to the current word
    editor.selection.setRng(selRng);
}
```

Below is a JS Fiddle for the same

https://jsfiddle.net/t9qhmguo/

[image: Output]

Comment: i'm on the latest tinymce and i get a "expand is not a function message"

Comment: @MirrorMirror, lot of things may have change since this is a 2+yr old answer. I would suggest you open a new issue for this